# No java virtual machine found

Tags: java, eclipse

I realize this question has been asked before, but it's been years since the last one with any good answers.

I've downloaded eclipse, extracted the files and tried to open it, but it comes up with this message.

"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
C:\Users\Riversong\Downloads\eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\jre
\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH"

What do I need to download or change to make this work?  I have Windows 7 and the latest Eclipse.  (On the Eclipse folder, I do not have eclipse.ini as file.  It is called eclipse instead but is still opened as a notepad file.)

Thank you!

Comment: install java and add it to your path

Comment: It's **not** recommended to do most of the things mentioned in that question's answer, including changing your system `PATH` environment variable. Using `eclipse.ini` *is* the recommended approach. See my answer below.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate; I'm pretty sure the problem here is due to Windows hiding the extension for the `eclipse.ini` file (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

Windows, by default, hides the extensions for many types of files. If you have a file that appears to be named `eclipse` but opens as a text file and has contents like those seen at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini then you've got the right file v(you can verify this by looking at the file's properties). Use the instructions on that page to add the `-vm` parameter so Eclipse knows where to find the JVM you want it to run in.

By the way, if you want to turn off this annoying feature of Windows, in File Explorer select the **Tools** menu, then **Folder options...**, then go to the **View** tab. There you can find a checkbox option labeled *Hide extensions for known file types*.